# Converting Array of `Float32` (`float`) to Array of `UINT8` (`unsigned char`) Using AVX2

Tags: performance, c, vectorization, x86, simd

Given input array of `Float32` (`float`) with `numElements` how could one efficiently convert it into array of `UINT8` (`unsigned char`)?
The tricky part here is to apply [Unsigned Saturation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141075) in the conversion

For instance, here is a vanilla code for it (Pay attention there is a scaling operation):

```
void ConvertToUint8(unsigned char* mO, float* mI, int numElements, float scalingFctr)
{
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < numElements; ii++) {
        mO[ii] = (unsigned char)(fmin(fmax(mI[ii] * scalingFctr, 0.0), 255.0));
    }
}
```

Where `mO` is the output array.

I'm looking for a way to optimize (Performance wise) this code on AVX2 enabled CPU's. Any idea, Intrinsics included, is welcome.

**Pay attention** the above code apply unsigned saturation manually (Is there a function for unsigned saturation based casting in `C`?). I think in practice `SSE` and AVX have it built in (See [`_mm_packus_epi16()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_packus_epi16&expand=3819,4109) for `SSE`).

The objective is to yield faster code than the vanilla example as in [Compiler Explorer - ConvertToUint8](https://godbolt.org/z/pCYd7V).

For simplicity one could assume the arrays are aligned.

Comment: Can the scale factor put the resulting float outside of the range of an int as well? That would be more annoying

Comment: Yes. You should assume `mI[ii] * scalingFctr` can have any legit `Float32` value (But not `NAN` or `INF`). I think in `SSE` the intrinsic `_mm_packus_epi16` does the trick

Comment: I don't think it works out so nicely, `vcvttps2dq` produces `INT_MIN` for out of range floats (including large positive), and then a pack-with-unsigned-saturation still interprets that as `INT_MIN` so it would result in zero, but maybe we wanted 0xFF. So it gets trickier

Comment: Harold, I tried to define the code more accurately. I mean that values after scaling which are lower than 0 will be clipped into zero and values above 255 will be clipped into 255.

Comment: C doesn't have a saturation cast operator built-in.

Answer (score 3):

Harold's comment is correct.

Consider what happens for float inputs like `5000000000 * 1.0`.  Conversion to `int32_t` with [`cvtps2dq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtps2dq) will give you `-2147483648` from that out-of-range positive `float`.  (2's complement integer bit-pattern `0x80000000` is the "indefinite integer value" described by Intel's documentation for this case.)

In that case, your vectorized version that clamps via integer saturation will start with a negative (and ultimately do unsigned saturation to 0), not matching your `fmin` which clamps before even converting to integer, resulting in 255.

**So you have to be able to rule out such inputs if you want to vectorize without clamping in the FP domain before conversion to integer.**

Remember that IEEE754 binary32 `float` can represent values outside the range of `int32_t` or `int64_t`, and what x86 FP->int conversions do in that case.

Comment: I see. In my case you can assume the range of values is within the range of `INT32`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tryout I cam up with - [`ConvertToUint8()`](https://godbolt.org/z/JaiSHr):

```
#include <immintrin.h> // AVX & AVX2

#define AVX_STRIDE          8
#define AVX_STRIDE_DOUBLE   16
#define AVX_STRIDE_TRIPLE   24
#define AVX_STRIDE_QUAD     32

void ConvertToUint8(unsigned char* mO, float* mI, int numElements, float scalingFctr)
{
    int ii;
    float *ptrInputImage;
    int *ptrOutputImage;

    __m256  floatPx1, floatPx2, floatPx3, floatPx4;
    __m256  scalingFactor;
    __m256i int32Px1, int32Px2, int32Px3, int32Px4;
    __m256i uint8Px1, uint8Px2;
    __m256i *ptrOutputImageAvx;

    for (ii = 0; ii < numElements; ii += AVX_STRIDE_QUAD) {
        ptrInputImage       = mI;
        ptrOutputImageAvx   = (__m256i*)(mO);
        // AVX Pack is 8 Floats (8 * 32 Bit) -> 32 UINT8 (32 * 8 Bit)
        // Hence loading 4 * 8 Floats which will be converted into 32 UINT8

        floatPx1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(ptrInputImage);
        floatPx2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(ptrInputImage + AVX_STRIDE);
        floatPx3 = _mm256_loadu_ps(ptrInputImage + AVX_STRIDE_DOUBLE);
        floatPx4 = _mm256_loadu_ps(ptrInputImage + AVX_STRIDE_TRIPLE);

        ptrInputImage += AVX_STRIDE_QUAD;

        // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778721
        int32Px1 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(_mm256_mul_ps(floatPx1, scalingFactor)); // Converts the 8 SP FP values of a to 8 Signed Integers (32 Bit).
        int32Px2 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(_mm256_mul_ps(floatPx2, scalingFactor));
        int32Px3 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(_mm256_mul_ps(floatPx3, scalingFactor));
        int32Px4 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(_mm256_mul_ps(floatPx4, scalingFactor));
        uint8Px1 = _mm256_packs_epi32(uint16Px1, uint16Px2); // Saturating and packing 2 of 8 Integers into 16 of INT16
        uint8Px2 = _mm256_packs_epi32(uint16Px3, uint16Px4); // Saturating and packing 2 of 8 Integers into 16 of INT16
        uint8Px1 = _mm256_packus_epi16(uint8Px1, uint8Px2); // Saturating and packing 2 of 16 INT16 into 32 of UINT8
        uint8Px1 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(uint8Px1, _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7)); // Permitation for Linear Orderinmg
        _mm256_storeu_si256(ptrOutputImageAvx++, uint8Px1); // Storing 32 UINT8, Promoting the pointer

    }
}
```

The code is based on [answer of Peter Cordes - How to Convert 32 [Bit] Float to 8 [Bit] Signed `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51779212/195787)?
I'd love to hear thoughts about it.

Comment: This looks like the code you actually want a review of.  You should put this in your question.  Your current codereview question is written like an SO question, asking for someone to vectorize it.  It should be written to ask for a review of *your* vectorization of it, with the scalar version working as documentation of what the vectorized code does.

Comment: I revised my question objective to match the site rules. So I'm not explicitly asks for intrinsics but open to any code that improve the performance of the vanilla code on AVX2 enabled CPU's.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of code review, and still trying to use it like Stack Overflow without even posting your own attempt at an optimized implementation.  There's very little to review in the code you posted as the question, as far as style or performance, because you're not even claiming it's an actual finished attempt at a good implementation.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Let's play a game. I'm a student on a university. You are my University [Research Software Engineer](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?page_id=2). I tell you I have a code which runs not fast enough on my research computer which has `AVX2`. I show you the code above and ask you to review it. What would you suggest me doing? On top of that, if you show me where my question doesn't fulfill the community guidelines I will vote closing it as well. On top of that, I don't understand why people even bother with it. Someone asks for assistance, can you assist?

Comment: It's not a codereview question because the answer you're really hoping/asking for is a complete rewrite using intrinsics.  You *know* the implementation in the question isn't what you want or close to efficient on any compiler.  Everything about how you present the problem is written as a StackOverflow question (which is a duplicate of [How to convert 32-bit float to 8-bit signed char?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51778721) because there isn't a faster way to multiply).  Unless your inputs and scaling factor are both exact integers, in which case you could use 16-bit integer multiply.

Comment: It might be interesting to ask on meta.codereview.SE whether this kind of question, asking for a major rewrite, is on-topic, to see how CR regulars explain it.

Comment: We had a talk about it on the Chat of CR.